is serial write to same port from multiple threads, thread safe?
In my application there are multiple serial port writer threads and only one serial port reader thread. I would like to know, is it thread safe to write to a serial port from multiple threads?
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity) {
    struct termios tty;
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
    tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                    // no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;            // read blocks
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;            // 0 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                    // enable reading
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= parity;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

const char *portname = "/dev/ttyUSB1";
int fd = -1;

void* writer(void* data) {
    const char* msg = (char*)data;
    while (true) {
        int cnt = 0, len = strlen(msg);
        while (cnt < len) {
            // is below call thread safe?
            int res = write(fd, &msg[cnt], len - cnt);
            if (res != -1) {
                cnt += res;
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void* reader(void*) {
    char buff[1024];
    while (true) {
        read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("error while opening port");
    }

    set_interface_attribs (fd, B115200, 0);  // set speed to 115,200 bps, 8n1 (no parity)

    pthread_t reader_thread;
    pthread_attr_t reader_thread_attribute;
    pthread_attr_init(&reader_thread_attribute);
    pthread_create(&reader_thread, &reader_thread_attribute, reader, NULL);

    pthread_t writer_thread1;
    pthread_attr_t writer_thread_attribute1;
    pthread_attr_init(&writer_thread_attribute1);
    pthread_create(&writer_thread1, &writer_thread_attribute1, writer, (void*)"writer1");


    pthread_t writer_thread2;
    pthread_attr_t writer_thread_attribute2;
    pthread_attr_init(&writer_thread_attribute2);
    pthread_create(&writer_thread2, &writer_thread_attribute2, writer, (void*)"writer1");

    pthread_join(reader_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(writer_thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(writer_thread2, NULL);

    close(fd);
}


Even if a single write() to a serial  terminal was thread safe, you still have the possible issue of an incomplete write(), i.e. a non-zero return (which your code ignores) indicating n bytes of the original request were not written and need to be re-submitted. Of course another write() would not be able to maintain "threadsafety" with respect to the prior write(). BTW your termios initialization is broken, i.e. hard assignments; see Setting Terminal Modes Properly

@sawdust in that case I need to use a mutex before calling write right?

Yes, that could suffice. But a more robust solution IMO is to consolidate and issue all write operations to the serial terminal from a single (third?) thread.
